# How do I run an interactive script on tty1 before user log on?

Tags: linux, bash, python, raspbian, tty

I have a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian Buster (headless) and want to have the system run a script at boot that presents an interactive menu to the user, using either bash dialog or curses / ncurses.  Is it possible to have the system present the interactive menu to the user for input without them first logging on?  N.B. the menu will use cursor keys and enter to interact with it - select an option to execute it.

Comment: I achieved this using openvt as follows:  openvt -c 1 -f -- /home/pi/mybashscript.sh

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this using openvt as follows: openvt -c 1 -f -- /home/pi/mybashscript.sh
I've added it to /etc/rc.local and it runs at start up without issues.